# Random failures when installing dependencies in ros industrial-ci pipeline

Tags: ros2, ros-industrial

Since yesterday(mar 26, 2024), we are getting random failures when installing dependencies either upstream or target dependencies. We are running latest ros2 rolling on Ubuntu Noble and using github.

Here's an example failure for install_upstream_dependencies:

```
executing command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-rolling-rclcpp]
E: Unable to locate package ros-rolling-rclcpp
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
apt: command [apt-get install -y -qq ros-rolling-rclcpp] failed
'( source /opt/ros/rolling/setup.bash && rosdep install -q --from-paths /home/runner/work/xxx/xxx/.work/upstream_ws/src --ignore-src -y | grep -E '(executing command)|(Setting up)' ; )' returned with 1
'install_upstream_dependencies' returned with code '1' after 0 min 9 sec
```

The particular package that it fails to find is random and different on every run. All these packages are available locally at my desktop when I query.

Any idea what is going on as none of our CI builds are working since yesterday.

Comment: There's no known issues for installing debian packages from rolling. If you're seeing repeated errors please turn on more debugging and find out what the underlying error is.